# How to save an ExpressionEngine date field from front end?

Tags: date, expressionengine

Is there a particular way to format date fields from the front end of a site in order to be saved to a corresponding date field in ExpressionEngine.

I have a Cartthrob form that saves the data being entered into an entry. One of the fields is a date field that captures a date entered by the user.  Currently when that form is saved, the date is always listed as 12/31/1969 7:00 PM. Here is the field:

```
<input type="date"  class="datepicker-unix" name="custom_data[order_needby_date]" />
```

The form is working, because if I change the field to a text input rather than a date field in the control panel, the date is saved. However, I would like to be able to easily sort the entries date in another template, so would like to keep the date in the control panel.

Thanks in advance!